# Creating static binary

Tags: file, static-linking, dynamic-linking, ldd

I want to run dynamically linked executable on a simulator. But the simulator supports only statically linked executables. So, I am using ELF statifier for converting dynamically linked executables into statically linked executables. 
When I am using file command on it, output states that it is dynamically linked
 ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xff353323798f9b709345f32b699cc73835dabc53, not stripped
but I am using ldd on it, the output states " not a dynamic executable"
What might be the possible reason for it? Is there any other way to convert dynamically linked executables into statically linked executables?

Comment: Why can't you *compile* static programs at build time?

Comment: Source code is not available. I have only executable.

Comment: In general it is *impossible* to convert an arbitrary dynamically linked executable into a static one. Read [Drepper's paper: How to Write Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)